# Есть ли ограничения при получении данных с DDE сервера?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Мне нужно получить данные от DDE сервера. Где-то на 16000 проходе цикла, я получаю кракозябры. Visual Studio 2010 Экспресс-выпуск, windows xp. НА Delphi такой проблемы нет. Что я делаю не так?

**UPD:** Мне кажется проблема с памятью?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "ddeml.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


HDDEDATA CALLBACK DdeCallback(
        UINT uType,     // Transaction type.
        UINT uFmt,      // Clipboard data format.
        HCONV hconv,    // Handle to the conversation.
        HSZ hsz1,       // Handle to a string.
        HSZ hsz2,       // Handle to a string.
        HDDEDATA hdata // Handle to a global memory object.
        ) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

   char* DDERequest(DWORD idInst, HCONV hConv, char* szItem)
    {   char *szResult = new char[255];
        HSZ hszItem = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, szItem, 0);
        HDDEDATA hData = DdeClientTransaction(NULL,0,hConv,hszItem,CF_TEXT,
                                     XTYP_REQUEST,999999999 , NULL);
        if (hData==NULL)
        {
            printf("Request failed: %s\n", szItem);
        }
        else
        {

            DdeGetData(hData, (unsigned char *)szResult, 255, 0);
          // printf("%s%s\n", sDesc, szResult);
        }
        return szResult;
    }


    int __cdecl main(void) 
    {

        //-----------------------------------------GET DDE DATA-----------------------------------------
       char szApp[] = "EXCEL";
        char szTopic[] = "sheet";

        int i;

  //DDE Initialization
    DWORD idInst=0;
    UINT iReturn;
    iReturn = DdeInitialize(&idInst, (PFNCALLBACK)DdeCallback,
                            APPCLASS_STANDARD | APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0 );
    if (iReturn!=DMLERR_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("DDE Initialization Failed: 0x%04x\n", iReturn);

    }else {printf("DDE Initialization: 0x%04x\n", iReturn);}


    //DDE Connect to Server using given AppName and topic.
    HSZ hszApp, hszTopic;
    HCONV hConv;
    hszApp = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, szApp, 0);
    hszTopic = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, szTopic, 0);
    hConv = DdeConnect(idInst, hszApp, hszTopic, NULL);
    DdeFreeStringHandle(idInst, hszApp);
    DdeFreeStringHandle(idInst, hszTopic);
    if (hConv == NULL)
    {
        printf("---------------------------------------------DDE Connection Failed.----------------------------------\n");

    }else{printf("DDE Connection Succeful.\n");}

    //Execute commands/requests specific to the DDE Server.
    for (int a=0;a<999999999;a++){

        printf("NUMBER ----------------------------%d-------------------------------\n",a);
        printf("rezult : %s\n",DDERequest(idInst, hConv, "R1C1"));

    }
    //DDE Disconnect and Uninitialize.
    DdeDisconnect(hConv);
    DdeUninitialize(idInst);
    system("pause");
    return 1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "ddeml.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


HDDEDATA CALLBACK DdeCallback(
        UINT uType,     // Transaction type.
        UINT uFmt,      // Clipboard data format.
        HCONV hconv,    // Handle to the conversation.
        HSZ hsz1,       // Handle to a string.
        HSZ hsz2,       // Handle to a string.
        HDDEDATA hdata // Handle to a global memory object.
        ) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
char *szResult = new char[255];
   char* DDERequest(DWORD idInst, HCONV hConv, char* szItem)
    {   //char *szResult = new char[255];
        HSZ hszItem = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, szItem, 0);
        HDDEDATA hData = DdeClientTransaction(NULL,0,hConv,hszItem,CF_TEXT,
                                     XTYP_REQUEST,5000 , NULL);
        if (hData==NULL)
        {
            printf("Request failed: %s\n", szItem);
        }
        else
        {

            DdeGetData(hData, (unsigned char *)szResult, 255, 0);
          // printf("%s%s\n", sDesc, szResult);
        }
        return szResult;
    }



    int __cdecl main(void) 
    {

        //-----------------------------------------GET DDE DATA-----------------------------------------
       char szApp[] = "GEHCS";
        char szTopic[] = "DATAGR";

        int i;

  //DDE Initialization
    DWORD idInst=0;
    UINT iReturn;
    iReturn = DdeInitialize(&idInst, (PFNCALLBACK)DdeCallback,
                            APPCLASS_STANDARD | APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0 );
    if (iReturn!=DMLERR_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("DDE Initialization Failed: 0x%04x\n", iReturn);

    }else {printf("DDE Initialization: 0x%04x\n", iReturn);}


    //DDE Connect to Server using given AppName and topic.
    HSZ hszApp, hszTopic;
    HCONV hConv;
    hszApp = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, szApp, 0);
    hszTopic = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, szTopic, 0);
    hConv = DdeConnect(idInst, hszApp, hszTopic, NULL);
    DdeFreeStringHandle(idInst, hszApp);
    DdeFreeStringHandle(idInst, hszTopic);
    if (hConv == NULL)
    {
        printf("---------------------------------------------DDE Connection Failed.----------------------------------\n");

    }else{printf("DDE Connection Succeful.\n");}

    //Execute commands/requests specific to the DDE Server.
    for (int a=0;a<9999999999;a++){
            DWORD idInst=0;
    UINT iReturn;
    iReturn = DdeInitialize(&idInst, (PFNCALLBACK)DdeCallback, APPCLASS_STANDARD | APPCMD_CLIENTONLY, 0 );


    hszApp = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, szApp, 0);
    hszTopic = DdeCreateStringHandle(idInst, szTopic, 0);
    hConv = DdeConnect(idInst, hszApp, hszTopic, NULL);
    DdeFreeStringHandle(idInst, hszApp);
    DdeFreeStringHandle(idInst, hszTopic);  
    printf("NUMBER ----------------------------%d-------------------------------\n",a);
    printf("rezult : %s\n",DDERequest(idInst, hConv, "%I2"));


    DdeDisconnect(hConv);
    DdeUninitialize(idInst);

    }
    //DDE Disconnect and Uninitialize.

    system("pause");
    return 1;

    }
```